# change subnavigation category url

Tags: url, layered-navigation, navigation, seo

can you change subnavigation subcategory urls to SEO friendly?  if so how?

ie:

existing = `store.com/apparel.html?cat=4`

desired = `store.com/apparel/shirts.html`
or anything close to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me explain first why is this difference.
In the first case you are viewing the 'apparel' category and filtering the results buy subcategory with id 4 (probably shirts). In the second case you are viewing the apparel->shirts category directly.

If you have special settings for the apparel category (like different design, different layout or sidebars) you will still be able to see those settings in the first case (?cat=4).

In the second case you will see the settings for the shirts category.

If you still want to use the friendly urls for filtering you can use an extension.
I recommend [Manadev Seo Layered Navigation](http://www.manadev.com/extensions/seo-layered-navigation-plus) and [Amasty improved Navigation](http://amasty.com/improved-navigation.html)
Both of them can be configured to behave like you want and even more.

Comment: I actually don't think Amasty's module can do that. It does have nice URL's for attribute filters, but the category filters are the same as stock Magento, and show up as `?cat=23`

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't actually do that. Response from Amasty Support: "Thank you for the screenshot and steps. The thing is that the 'Category Filter Seelct' feature (which is enabled) in a beta release so it doesn't generate SEO friendly URLs"

Answer (score 2):

I created a module that solves this error.

https://github.com/jruzafa/Devopensource_LayerCatSeo

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

This can be fixed quite easily by overriding the `getUrl()` method in the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Item class`

```
(Go to /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Item.php)
```

Locate the function at line 57, it should look like this:

```
 public function getUrl()
 {
        $query = array(
        $this->getFilter()->getRequestVar()=>$this->getValue(),
        Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_pager')->getPageVarName() => null // exclude current page from urls);
        return Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current'=>true, '_use_rewrite'=>true, '_query'=>$query));
  }
```

Change to :

```
public function getUrl()
{
    if($this->getFilter()->getRequestVar() == "cat"){
        $category_url = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->getValue())->getUrl();
        $return = $category_url;
        $request = Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current'=>true, '_use_rewrite'=>true));
        if(strpos($request,'?') !== false ){
            $query_string = substr($request,strpos($request,'?'));
        }
        else{
            $query_string = '';
        }
        if(!empty($query_string)){
            $return .= $query_string;
        }
        return $return;
    }
    else{
        $query = array(
            $this->getFilter()->getRequestVar()=>$this->getValue(),
            Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_pager')->getPageVarName() => null // exclude current page from urls
        );

        return Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current'=>true, '_use_rewrite'=>true, '_query'=>$query));
    }
}
```