# Category sidebar use SEO url vs cat=

Tags: magento-1.9, category, sidebar

Currently on my site when I visit a top level category from the sidebar the URL is: `http://example.com/top-level-category`

Then when I click a sub-category in the resulting sidebar the URL is: `http://example.com/top-level-category?cat=123`.

I would expect the URL to be the URL of the sub-category, i.e.: `http://example.com/top-level-category/sub-category`

Is there a way to get the category sidebar to use the SEO friendly-url instead of `cat=123` for subcategories?

Comment: Did you get this resolved? I have the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off Anchor mode for the top-level-category, which will cause the sub-category links in the resulting sidebar to become links to the category page instead of filters that have an URL like `cat=123`.

Also see this question/answer:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/2792

If you want to keep the filters, you'll need to use a third-party module